# How to setup 2 domain on one XAMPP server on the same port?

Tags: php, apache, xampp, vhosts, apache2.4

I have two different PHP application running on XAMPP server.

I need to be able to access both application using two different domain.

The first application will be local to the server "dev.app".
The second app will be accessible from the internal network "staging.domain.com"

The internal IP for the server is 10.0.4.18.

In the `httpd.conf` I added the following line to run XAMPP on `10.0.4.18`

```
Listen 10.0.4.18:80
```

Additionally, in the `httpd-vhosts.conf` I added the following code

```
#Staging
<VirtualHost *:443>

    DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs/staging"
    ServerAdmin mikea@domain.com
    ServerName staging.domain.com
    ServerAlias staging.domain.com

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"

    <Directory "F:/xampp/htdocs/staging">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all Granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

#dev
<VirtualHost *:443>

    DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs/dev/public"
    ServerAdmin mikea@domain.com
    ServerName dev.app
    ServerAlias dev.app

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"

    <Directory "F:/xampp/htdocs/dev/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all Granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

My hosts file looks like this

```
127.0.0.1        localhost
127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1
10.0.4.18        dev.app
```

However, when I open "dev.app" from the local server's browser, it redirects me to staging.domain.com.

How can I be able to access both domain without interfering?

Comment: instead of the `<VirtualHost *:443>` make it `<VirtualHost domainname:443>`. Essentially the first one is just matching all domains (or if reverse, the last one is overwriting the config for the first because it is set to the same match).

Comment: @JonathanKuhn still the same problem. I get redirected to staging.domain.com when I try to open dev.app

Comment: Oops, sorry, that is usually for IP, not domain. Looking over the manual, your original configuration should work fine. Are you restarting apache when you make these changes?

Comment: I do restart the server yet. does it make any difference here that I am using port 443 ssl not 80

Comment: It actually might. You would need to access the server with `https` and likely have setup an ssl certificate.

Comment: aha. yes that worked. I had to do https://dev.app for it to work. thank you